# middleware in Laravel 5.0

Tags: laravel

Есть Laravel 5.0 со стандартной авторизацией, пытаюсь написать middleware, который будет проверять что если заходит админ, то пускает его в любом случае, если не админ, то смотрит есть ли ip-адрес в таблице разрешенных адресов, если нет его там то не пускает, ели есть пускает, но пишет ошибку, подскажите в чем проблема ?

route:

```
Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
])->middleware(['Ipcheck']);
```

kernel:

```
...
'ipcheck' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Ipcheck',
...
```

сам midleware:

```
use Closure;
use Request;
use App\iptable;

class Ipcheck {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (\Auth::user()->is_admin)
        {
            return $next($request);
        }
        else
        {
            $ip = Request::ip();
            $iplist = iptable::all();

            function applyNetMask($ip, $mask)
            {
                if ( is_string($ip  ) ) $ip   = ip2long($ip  );
                if ( is_string($mask) ) $mask = ip2long($mask);

                return long2ip(sprintf('%u', $ip & $mask));
            }   

            foreach ($iplist as $iplist) {
                if($iplist->adds !== applyNetMask($ip, $iplist->mask))
                    return 'Ты не пройдешь !');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот кусок кода берет первый `$iplist` и при несоответствии - выбрасывает, с последующими не сверяет. Стоит возвращать сообщение после завершения массива, а прерывать его при нахождении соответствия.

```
foreach ($iplist as $iplist) {
    if($iplist->adds !== applyNetMask($ip, $iplist->mask))
        return 'Ты не пройдешь !');
}
```

---

Тут вы объявляете функцию. Работает только до тех пор, пока `Ipcheck::handle()` не будет вызван во второй раз. Но, вроде, и не должен.

```
function applyNetMask($ip, $mask) {...}
```

---

Если пользоваель - Админ (он авторизован), то зачем ему авторизация?

```
if (\Auth::user()->is_admin) {...}
```

---

Какая ошибка - не понятно.

*> telepathic mode: off*
*>*_

Comment: Мол если он админ, то его айпи не проверяем, если он обычный человек, смотрим с какого айпи он заходит, если с разрешенного.то милости просим, если плохой. то до свидания...
Разобрался, там возвращался null так как я его повесил этот middleware на
Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
])->middleware(['Ipcheck']);
в этот момент он еще не авторизирован, интересно было просто, не смог справиться, сделал по-другому

Comment: > _в этот момент он еще не авторизирован_ - об этом я и спрашивал в последнем абзаце

Comment: пересмотрел логику, спасибо. все исправил

Answer (score 0):

Решение для Laravel 5.*
Пойти в контроллер логина:

```
app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php
```

Там найти и определить метод:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
  {
    // Сверить данные со списком и сделать что-то с юзером, который только что залогинился
  }
```